# Grieved at / with / by

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

What will  follow grieved in the following sentence ?

> I was very much grieved ______his misdemeanor.

I have four options to choose from .
At /
With /
By /
Of

In my opinion **by** fits best  , but my book says it should be **at** .

Comment: This usage is rather old-fashioned. Nowadays, there is no clear preference for the one or the other preposition. I'd probably not use **grieved** here at all, but would say "aggrieved by".

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is

> aggrieved - *feeling resentment at having been unfairly treated*

not

> grieved - *suffer grief/sadness/loss*

and the usual pattern is

> aggrieved **by** *something*

since the person's action caused the effect on you, using **at** does not necessarily have the same implication. You would also not usually say **misdemeanor** which is a legal term to describe the severity of an action.

> I was very much aggrieved **by** his *actions*.